# Wamp Server on local machine responds to ping but port 80 comes up as closed

Tags: apache-http-server, wamp, godaddy

I recently registered the domain `politicsapp.us` with GoDaddy and I am trying to set up a server on my local machine with WampServer. I set it all up, but when i type that into a browser, it gives me `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

I first tried to ping the URL and got the following response

```
C:\Users\Admin>ping politicsapp.us

Pinging politicsapp.us [71.228.29.37] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 71.228.29.37: bytes=32 time=18ms TTL=63
Reply from 71.228.29.37: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=63
Reply from 71.228.29.37: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=63
Reply from 71.228.29.37: bytes=32 time=13ms TTL=63

Ping statistics for 71.228.29.37:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 10ms, Maximum = 18ms, Average = 13ms

C:\Users\Admin>
```

So ping works. And the domain is pointing to the right place. I checked my router and port 80 is in fact forwarding to this machine. But [PortChecker](http://portchecker.co/check) is telling me that my port is closed. I have added a rule to allow all incoming port 80 connections in Windows Firewall.

What's the problem?

Some additional requested info:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Windows\system32> netstat -abo | FINDSTR LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:21             Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1552
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       4024
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       832
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       2644
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:12025          Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    0.0.0.0:12110          Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    0.0.0.0:12119          Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    0.0.0.0:12143          Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    0.0.0.0:12465          Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    0.0.0.0:12563          Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    0.0.0.0:12993          Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    0.0.0.0:12995          Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    0.0.0.0:27275          Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       504
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       932
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       628
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       996
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49165          Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       616
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49626          Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       4716
  TCP    127.0.0.1:12025        Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    127.0.0.1:12110        Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    127.0.0.1:12119        Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    127.0.0.1:12143        Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    127.0.0.1:12465        Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    127.0.0.1:12563        Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    127.0.0.1:12993        Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    127.0.0.1:12995        Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    127.0.0.1:14147        Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1552
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27275        Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    192.168.1.34:139       Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:21                Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1552
  TCP    [::]:80                Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       4024
  TCP    [::]:135               Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       832
  TCP    [::]:445               Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:3306              Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       2644
  TCP    [::]:5357              Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       4
  TCP    [::]:49152             Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       504
  TCP    [::]:49153             Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       932
  TCP    [::]:49154             Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       628
  TCP    [::]:49155             Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       996
  TCP    [::]:49165             Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       616
  TCP    [::]:49626             Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       4716
  TCP    [::1]:12025            Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    [::1]:12110            Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    [::1]:12119            Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    [::1]:12143            Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    [::1]:12465            Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    [::1]:12563            Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    [::1]:12993            Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    [::1]:12995            Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
  TCP    [::1]:14147            Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1552
  TCP    [::1]:27275            Admin-PC:0             LISTENING       1300
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: No, I cannot access the website from either of the two. @Steven

Comment: Is your WAMPServer set to "Online" mode?  If not, your Apache server will only accept connections from your local machine.

Comment: Yes, it is set to online mode @Steven

Comment: Yes, it is green @Steven

Comment: Can you access the webpage at http://127.0.0.1 from that computer?

Comment: Yes, it is going to my WampServer landing screen. @Steven

Comment: please post the output of `netstat -abo | FINDSTR LISTENING` from an elevated powershell window. you need to confirm that there is a listener for tcp\80 pointing to your webserver process, and that the IP address it is listening on is either 0.0.0.0 or 71.228.29.37

Comment: @FrankThomas Ok, I posted it. Hope that helps.

Comment: well, that output looks good. Apache has been correctly configured to listen. so is TCP\80 allowed incoming in your local firewall?

Comment: from a system on the same lan as the server, check the port with telnet: `telnet 192.168.1.34 80`. if you don't see a message that the connection was refused, then the port is open to the lan, and the issue is in your router configuration. if you do get a connection refused, then then problem is in the local firewall. Note that on windows you may have to install telnet from appwiz.cpl -> turn windows features on or off.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the ip address `71.228.29.37` is your routers WAN ip address.

In that case you are getting GoDaddies DNS to point to your ipaddress and you need to Port Forard your router to allow connections made to this ip address to be forwarded from the routers port 80 to the internal PC's ip address's port 80 and therefore to Apache.

See this site http://portforward.com/ for help in setting up port forwarding on your particular router.

Also make sure that your PC running WAMPServer is setup with a static ip address.

Comment: Since  a ping to domain politicsapp.us is working successfully it means DNS setup working fine.  Probably there is a need to re-check #1 port forwarding to the computer and #2 firewall setting to open the port and finally online port checking can be done using any [Port Checker](https://www.portcheckers.com/)  website.

Comment: @geekonweb You do realise this question is now 7 years old? Right??